# Graphing the sine function - a period of it

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot a period of the sine function. The following code did not give me the appropriate graph.  Should I plot it using degrees or radians?  (How do I put a legend "y = sin(x)" in a box directly under the y-axis?)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3.14159,xmax=3.14159,
    domain=-3.14159:3.14159, samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-1.25,ymax=1.25,
    restrict y to domain=-1.25:1.25,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,blue] {sin(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is sampled with radians points however assumes degree input. You either need to add `trig format=rad` or use the function as `sin(deg(x))`. Then it draws correctly.

Comment: I used the specification `xmin=-1.5708,xmax=1.5708,
domain=-1.5708:1.5708,` in the optional commands for the axis and the command `\addplot[samples=501,domain=-1.5708:1.5708,blue] {sin(deg(x))};`. It does give the correct plot.  Does `deg(x)` convert the numbers in the domain to degrees and evaluate the sine function at the equivalent number in degrees?

Comment: @Adelyn Yes. The domain is sampled as much as you specified so it evaluates at `-pi/2`,`-pi/2+pi/500`... but these numbers are supplied to sin function which expects degrees. deg(s) converts it